# Junit for @Bean

Tags: junit, configuration, annotations

I have a configuration class as below :

```
@Configuration()
public class JsonConfiguration {

    /** Default constructor. */
    protected JsonConfiguration() {
    }

     /**
     * Overrides the default jackson mapper builder to remove empty/null values from returned json.
     * @return the customised jackson mapper.
     */
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder b = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
            .serializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
        return b;
    }
}
```

I need to unit test my method "jacksonBuilder".

Can someone help me as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did some research and found the answer to the same.

Below is the code I wrote for the test, just in case anyone is stuck at the same point, please refer below :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class JsonConfigurationTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public JsonConfiguration orderService() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
            Constructor<JsonConfiguration> constructor = JsonConfiguration.class
                    .getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[0]);
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            JsonConfiguration conf= constructor.newInstance(new Object[0]);
            return conf;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private JsonConfiguration configuration;

    @Test
    public void jacksonBuilderTest() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = configuration.jacksonBuilder();
        assertNotNull(builder);
    }

}
```